# Subsets of real numbers that aren't complete

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

If all bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ have an infimum and a supremum, then why does a bounded subset consisting of only rational numbers (such as $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:x^2<2\}$) break the property? Isn't it a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ since $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The supremum/infimum need only lie in $\mathbb{R}$ not the set itself.

Comment: It doesnt't break the property. As a subset of $\mathbb R$ (this is important!) it has supremum $\sqrt{2}$ and infimum $-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: It has a supremum **in $\mathbb{R}$**, but it does _not_ have a supremum **in $\mathbb{Q}$**.

Comment: Oh, of course. That makes sense.